# How to display Woocommerce variations prices and descriptions

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm building a template page for my own woocommerce theme.

**[ISSUE:]**
While I call the function ***woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart*** it show the section which contain the html output of the variations' dropwown and the descriptions/prices related on current selected variation. All right, it do the output correctly inside the proper div element, like this:

```
<div class="single_variation_wrap">
    <div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation" style="">
        <div class="woocommerce-variation-description">
            <p>Option 1 description</p>
        </div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-price">
    etc....
```

I need to separate this section from the dropdown's html output, so I wrote the code to show only the dropdown and it work, but I'm unable to show again the dynamic description and price!
Which is the correct function to call in order to show just the variation's description and its price?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use result, returned from `wc_get_product` for showing required data. `$_product = wc_get_product( $product_id );`

Comment: SOLVED: I found the template part which call the code about price variations. It is inside: /mytheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variation.php

Answer (score 1):

If you have the variation id, you can use PHP code like this :

```
$variation = wc_get_product( '14803' );

echo $variation->get_description();
echo $variation->get_price();
```

[Source](https://wpsites.net/product/get-display-variation-description-on-single-products/)

Answer (score -2):

`$_product = wc_get_product( $product_id );`

This displays price:  `$_product->get_price()`

This displays description: `$_product->get_variation_description()`

Comment: This doesn't get either the price or description, but throws errors for calling on a member function.

Comment: You need to show how to get the $product_id for the variation.